# docker image of sonarqube is not running with mysql db configuration

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker image of sonarqube with mysql db by below dockercommand:

```
sudo docker run -d --name hg-sonarqube \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME='sonar' \
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD='sonar' \
    -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance' \
    sonarqube
```

But container is not running due to error:

```
2016.12.28 11:20:11 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2016.12.28 11:20:11 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
```

MySQL service is running and sonar database. I use command to create database and give privileges in Ubuntu-14.04.

```
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'welcome123'; flush privileges;" | mysql -u root -pwelcome123

echo "CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; CREATE USER 'sonar' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar'; GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar'; flush privileges;" | mysql -u root -pwelcome123
```

Full Log file:

```
2016.12.28 11:19:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2016.12.28 11:19:58 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process5713024831851311243properties
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting es
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.s.s.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] version[2.3.5], pid[18], build[90f439f/2016-07-27T10:36:52Z]
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initializing ...
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.e.plugins] [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [24.2gb], net total_space [28.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
2016.12.28 11:19:59 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.env] [sonarqube] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2016.12.28 11:20:03 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] initialized
2016.12.28 11:20:03 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] starting ...
2016.12.28 11:20:03 INFO  es[][o.e.transport] [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2016.12.28 11:20:03 INFO  es[][o.e.discovery] [sonarqube] sonarqube/CPgnfx6NTe2aO07d6fR0Bg
2016.12.28 11:20:06 INFO  es[][o.e.cluster.service] [sonarqube] new_master {sonarqube}{CPgnfx6NTe2aO07d6fR0Bg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube, master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2016.12.28 11:20:06 INFO  es[][o.elasticsearch.node] [sonarqube] started
2016.12.28 11:20:06 INFO  es[][o.e.gateway] [sonarqube] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2016.12.28 11:20:06 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.12.28 11:20:06 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process6242669754365841464properties
2016.12.28 11:20:08 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.12.28 11:20:08 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonarqube/web
2016.12.28 11:20:08 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.12.28 11:20:08 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.12.28 11:20:09 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Bushwacker] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2016.12.28 11:20:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2016.12.28 11:20:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.2 / 4a28f29f95254b58f3cf0a0871bc632e998403f5
2016.12.28 11:20:11 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2016.12.28 11:20:11 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:88)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:175)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful for those who still facing this issue

You might be running mysql in another container. You can use below docker-compose file to make it in the same network

```
# Use sonar/sonar as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:5.1.1
    networks:
     - sonarqube-network
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true

  db:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - sonarqube-network
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sonar
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=sonar
     - MYSQL_USER=sonar
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sonar

networks:
  sonarqube-network:
```

Save the file as `docker-compose.yml` and run `docker-compose up`

Please note this entry,

```
- 3306:3306
```

After that try with,

```
mysql -u sonar -h localhost -p
```

to connect to MySQL